# Angular 10 i18n .htaccess to redirect to subfolders and remove the subfolder from the URL

Tags: angular, .htaccess, internationalization

Due to i18n use in Angular 10 I got three copies of the same project in diferent directories and all is working fine. The distribution on my server is as follows:

- www.mydomain.com/frontend/en/(angular project in english)
- www.mydomain.com/frontend/es/(angular project in spanish)
- www.mydomain.com/frontend/fr/(angular project in french)

When a user comes to [www.mydomain.com/frontend](http://www.mydomain.com/frontend) I managed to redirect them to the correct subfolder with the following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^../index\.html$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (..) $1/index.html [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /frontend/en/ [R]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /frontend/es/ [R]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /frontend/fr/ [R]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^es [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /frontend/en/ [R]

</IfModule>
```

And now I want that besides of redirecting them also remove the part of the locale from the url but I can't manage to do that. If someone can help me I will apreciate it.

As a final example if someone with the browser in spanish comes to my site the URL that he or she should see is www.mydomain.com/frontend/(angular project in spanish)

Comment: "now I want that besides of redirecting them also remove the part of the locale from the URL" - but isn't that the opposite of what you've already implemented?!

Comment: I assume the `.htaccess` file you've posted is inside the `/frontend` subdirectory? That 2nd rule is rather dubious... it unconditionally rewrites anything that does not exist to a subdirectory consisting of the first 2 characters of the requested URL-path, so it is dependent on the 2-letter language code being present in the URL.